# How to make buttons centralised when viewed from a smaller screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons on the same row but when the website is viewed on a smaller screen and the buttons are forced to be in two rows, the second button is not centralised.

[image: Viewed from a laptop]
Viewed from a laptop

[image: Viewed from a phone]

Viewed from a phone

```
<span class="inline" style="">
    <a href="/mgconsole" class="btn btn-theme"><strong>Login to ASDADSADASDAS</strong></a>
    <a href="/idx/verify" class="btn btn-outline" style="margin: 15px;"><strong>I Want to SDSDASDDSADASDASDASDASD</strong></a>
 </span>
```

How do I make the second button centralised?

Comment: please share your html and css

Comment: Make sure the button is smaller than the DIV? In this case, your button has more width than the DIV container it is in.

Comment: @Chris Code Shared.

Comment: @Shadowfox how should I  change it?

Comment: Edit your post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the grid feature eg:

If you want the button on 2 rows for small device and on 1 row  for others you could use different grid width (12 for small 6 for others)

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Enter</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Exit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the property `text-align: center;` on your button.

Comment: the problem persists even when `text-align: center;` is added

Answer (score 0):

Just tell me if this one is not sweet

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">

        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Enter</button>
             </div>

             <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Exit</button>
             </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: with your approach, the size of the two buttons will vary according to the width of the screen and they will never be forced to be in two rows. I still want the buttons to be on two rows and both buttons need to be centralised.

Comment: What do you think about the new answer? In case you already have something better it should great to share with us. It also help others who may have a similar problem tomorrow.